Standalone components in initial bundle
I am using Angular 18, and I have a problem with one of my modules.
I checked initial bundles using 'source-map-explorer' plugin, and I see that 3 components (all of them are standalone components) from one module are placed in initial bundle. They are only used within this module.
I do not understand why those 3 components are placed in initial bundle/chunk, and they are loaded on application startup. I'm expecting they are put in module news' bundle, and loaded only on news' pages.
Do you have any suggestion what can I check to solve this issue?
App Routing def
provideRouter(
  {..},
  {
    path: 'news',
    loadChildren: () => import('./news/news.module').then((m) => m.NewsModule),
    canMatch: [() => enabledFeatures.newsSection],
    canActivate: [authGuardCanActivate],
  }
)

Module def
@NgModule({
  imports: [NewsRoutingModule, NgxsModule.forFeature(newsStateObjects)],
})
export class NewsModule {}

Module routing:
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(
    { path: '', component: NewsDashboardComponent },
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class NewsRoutingModule {}

Component def
@Component({
  selector: 'app-news-item',
  templateUrl: './news-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./news-item.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [
NgOptimizedImage,MiddleClickDirectiveDirective,NgClass, NewsItemUserLabelsComponent,DatePipe, 
    TranslateModule,TimeAgoPipe, MatCard,MatCardTitle, MatCardSubtitle,
    MatCardContent, MatTooltip,MatCardActions, MatButton,MatIcon,
  ],
})
export class NewsItemComponent {}

source-map-explorer output image:
please note that there is separate bundle for news module, but it is not visible on below image


Whatever components you have defined in your NewsModule will be loaded once the user hits the route news. Since you are using modules, your standalone components should be added into the news module imports so, again, once the route news is reached, all within that module is loaded. What is your expectation? To not see the standalone components loaded into news module?

Please clarify what's the problem.

I updated the description and added output image from source-map-explorer.
This is a description of my problem:
I do not understand why those 3 components are placed in initial bundle/chunk, and they are loaded on application startup. I expect they are put in 'module news' bundle, and loaded only on news' pages.

To fully leverage standalone components and lazy loading you should avoid modules entirely and simply provide a routing document.
A simplified example to demonstrate this is given below:


// app.routes.ts

export const APP_ROUTES: Route[] = [
    {
        path: 'news',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./features/news/news.routes').then(
                (mod) => mod.NEWS_ROUTES
            ),
    },
  ]

// news.routes.ts

export const NEWS_ROUTES: Route[] = [

            {
                path: 'overview',
                loadComponent: () =>
                    import(
                        '../news/news-overview/news-overview.component'
                    ).then((m) => m.NewsOverviewComponent),
            },
            {
                path: 'article' + '/:articleId',
                loadComponent: () =>
                    import(
                        '../news/news-article/news-article.component'
                    ).then((m) => m.NewsArticleComponent),
            }
    ]

Using this approach means that no component is loaded until its route is explicitly navigated to, leaving you with a minimal initial bundle.
